# Get Primary Keys from GET Method Retrofit Android

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

So I am trying to fetch all desks to display them in the recyclerView (I display them without the primary key). That works okay.
But next I need each desks' id (primary key). I have the following code and it gives me 0 as a primary key for each desk.

This is the Desk class in my API

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "desk")
    public class DeskModel {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int desk_id;
    int ordinal_number;
    int available;

    public DeskModel() {
        super();
    }

    public DeskModel(int desk_id, int ordinal_number, int available) {
        super();
        this.desk_id = desk_id;
        this.ordinal_number = ordinal_number;
        this.available = available;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return desk_id;
    }

    public void setId(int desk_id) {
        this.desk_id = desk_id;
    }

    public int getAvailable() {
        return available;
    }

    public void setAvailable(int available) {
        this.available = available;
    }

    public int getOrdinal_number() {
        return ordinal_number;
    }

    public void setOrdinal_number(int ordinal_number) {
        this.ordinal_number = ordinal_number;
    }
    
}
```

This is the data Desk class in my Andorid Studio

```
data class Desk (
var desk_id : Int,
var ordinal_number : Int,
var available : Int)
```

This is the method for fetching all Desks in Android

```
api.fetchAllDesks().enqueue(object : Callback<List<Desk>> {

            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<List<Desk>>,
                response: Response<List<Desk>>
            ) {
                for(desk in response.body()!!){
                    deskNumbes.add(desk.ordinal_number.toString()) //array with just ordinal numers
                    desks.add(desk) //array with object Desk
                }

                adapterDesk.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Desk>>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.d("Error", t.message!!)
            }
        })
```

When I try to execute the following code to display the id of a specific desk it returns 0 even though it has another value in the databse (this happens for all positions)

```
        val deskId = desks[desk].desk_id
        Toast.makeText(this.requireContext(), deskId.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

What should I do to get the correct desk_id ? All the rows in the table in the database correspond with the names in my classes..

Comment: Does it return any other value? For example does it respond with the object Desk?

Comment: How did you create the array Desks? I suggest to use a MutableList of desks

Comment: @EnricoMosca I changed the code in OnResponse  to desks = (response.body() as ArrayList<Desk>?)!! and I continued with a different approach

Comment: Let us know if it worked!

Comment: @EnricoMosca yes it is working fine now